# Is Active Directory Domain possible inside Windows Docker Image using Windows Server Core?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, active-directory, windows-server

Have anyone **installed Active Directory Domain on microsoft/windowsservercore** image?

Is it working - can one add users and can they login via domain?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be a better question for Server Fault than Stack Overflow as this is a system administration question rather than a scripting question.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fin an answer? 
I suppose, that it should be technically possible, you're just running container and installing AD in it.